# How to cast an item & get selected items inside in sitecore?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, sitecore, ienumerable

**Hi Guys,**

Can anyone suggest better solution if it's not good approach,
I have an `IEnumerable<Item> locations` which contains multiple locations.
each item in this  `IEnumerable` contains a `MultilistField`.
I wants to select items by their Ids(`GUID`),
I am using something like below,

```
locations = locations.Where(x => ((MultilistField)x.Fields["Services"]).GetItems().Where(y => y.ID.Equals(serviceId)));
```

But it is giving me error:

> ERROR1: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type `'System.Func<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item,bool>'` because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> ERROR2: Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>'` to `'bool'`

Comment: Can you show definition of `locations`?

Comment: IEnumerable<Item> locations

Comment: Instead of `Where` you need `Any` in this line `locations = locations.Where(x => ((MultilistField)x.Fields["Services"]).GetItems().Any(y => y.ID.Equals(serviceId)));`, this will solve 2nd error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simpler approach which bypasses the casting of `MultiListField` objects:

```csharp
locations = locations.Where(item => item["Services"].Split('|').Contains(serviceId));
```

I have used 2 little shortcuts here:

1. The `Services` field value can be read as a simple pipe separated string of GUIDs.
2. Using `item["Services"]` instead of `item.Fields["Services"]` will return
   an empty string if there are no values or the field doesn't exist, never null.

If you really want to use the longer version:

```
locations = locations.Where(x => ((MultilistField)x.Fields["Services"]).GetItems().Any(y => y.ID.Equals(serviceId)));
```

Notice the use of `Any` instead of the second `Where`. You're not selecting the MultiList items. You're checking for any matches.